# Can't stream hd on Ubuntu but can easily on Windows

Tags: stream

hi i have my laptop dual booted with windows 7 and the newest version of Ubuntu. On windows i can easily stream hd programs from iplayer with no stuttering but on Ubuntu its very stuttery and even unwatchable. also when on Ubuntu i also cant even stream not so good quality programs in fullscreen as that stutters to. is there anything i can do? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using ffmpeg?

Comment: Though not entirely out of place here, your question might be better asked in an iPlayer support forum - http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/mbiplayer/NF8035762

Comment: It would be great if you posted how you used ffmpeg as an answer so you you can mark this question as solved!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Flash player that iPlayer uses is not as good running under Linux. I have the same problem and there is no fix until Flash player improves (or your CPU magically gets a lot quicker).

Comment: Could you please post how you got ffmpeg to work etc so that others may benefit from the knowledge? Also don't forget to mark your question as solved!